# Проблемы при самообучении по php (книга Р.Никсона)

Tags: php

Добрый день.
Возникли проблимы во время практики при самообучении по книге Робина Никсона - Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, CSS и HTML5. 3-е изд - 2015.

На странице 173 (Изучение PHP > создание файла) требуется ввести код для создания файла и проверить в браузере результат.

Ввожу следующий код в sublime text:

```
<?php
$fh = fopen("testfile.txt", 'w') or die("Создать файл не удалось");

$text = <<<_END
Строка 1
Строка 2
Строка 3
_END;
fwrite($fh, $text) or die("Сбой записи файла");
fclose($fh);
echo "Файл 'testfile.txt' записан успешно";
```

Затем сохраняю файл под именем testfile.txt и testfile.php, открываю в браузере, но ничего не просиходит.

Тоже самое и при вводе других примеров (функции print итд. - отображается какая-то билиберда в окне браузере).
Что и как вводить - в учебнике не написано.
Что я делаю не так?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете запускать php как скрипт из [консоли](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.usage.php)

```
$ php my_script.php
```

или настроить [webserver](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.webserver.php) и размещать свои скрипты там.

Comment: А где это нужно вводить? Не очень понятно.

Comment: в командной строке Windows или console в Linux или Mac.